# Why aren't my javascript functions running?

Tags: javascript, function, validation, if-statement

I have several functions on my web page that aren't working, here is one -

```
    <p> Change background color</p>
    <input name="bg" value="cyan" id="cyan" type="radio" onclick="changebgcolor(this);">"Cyan"
    <input name="bg" value="magenta" id="magenta" type="radio" onclick="changebgcolor(this);">"Magenta"
    <input name="bg" value="lightsalmon" id="lightsalmon" type="radio" onclick="changebgcolor(this);">"Light Salmon"

        function changebgcolor(element){
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = element.value;
        };
```

Console is telling me my elements are not defined?

The other one is a similar function intended to change text color, the rest are form validations.
and here is the web page I am working on - 
http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~mariaroo/validation.html

Comment: Did you view the console? Their is a lot of errors.

Comment: There is an `if` missing in the line `else (color == "lightsalmon"){`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed a lot of it, the text color still isn't working but I don't see any errors in the console...

Comment: Your validate zip method needs brackets `if zip.length < 5` to `if (zip.length < 5)`

Answer (score 0):

An `else` statement is not followed by a condition. You need to change your last `else` to an `else if` or remove the condition altogether:

```
// if you plan on adding more color options go this route
else if (color == "lightsalmon"){ 
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "lightsalmon"
}

// if you're not going to add any more color options this will work as well
else { 
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "lightsalmon"
}
```

#### EDIT

It looks like you've updated your code and the new issue is that when your HTML is parsed the `changebgcolor` and `changetextcolor` functions don't exist yet (they are at the bottom of your page). To fix this move them up into the `<head>` portion of your document so they are already initialized **before** your radio buttons and their `onclick` event handler is registered. See my example below:

```
<head>

... // you have meta, title and styling here

  <script>
    function changebgcolor(element){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = element.value;
    };

    function changetextcolor(element){
        document.body.style.color = element.value;
    };
  </script>
</head>
```